# Set the tick in CheckBox before Database call is made

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, checkbox, draw

I have a standard CheckBox and on the CheckChanged event I make a call to the database to refresh a result set else where. However the database call can take about a second which causes the tick that is drawn in the checkbox to be delayed which could cause the user to click again and again. You know what users are like!!

So, is there anyway that I can make the tick draw before the database call is made???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you do not make the database call on the UI thread. Instead use  [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) or just spin up another thread.

However, if you just want to control the user clicking the checkbox again simply set the control to disabled and tell the user to wait via the cursor:

```
public void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   CheckBox.Enabled = false;
   Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
   //Long Running database operation
   Cursor = Cursor.Default;
   CheckBox.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't perform the slow database call on the UI thread.  Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).
Another option would be to make use of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

```
private void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew<MyResultData>(DoLongOperation)
                .ContinueWith(UpdateUI, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private MyResultData DoLongOperation()
{
    // Long operation

    // Return result to be used to update the UI
    return new MyResultData();
}

private void UpdateUI(Task<MyResultData> task)
{
    // Get the result of the task
    MyResultData data = task.Result;

    // Update the UI using the data
}
```

Using tasks, you'll also get the benefit of being able to use the new async-await feature when/if you'll target your code to .NET 4.5 in the future.

Comment: Async/await is in .NET 4.5, not 5.